# TFS Build stopped running web deploy after .NET core install

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I have had webdeploy running for YEARS on a Windows Server 2012 machine with standard MSBuild arguments ([like this](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/creating-a-build-definition-that-supports-deployment)).

Yesterday I installed the `Windows (Server Hosting)` version of the `.NET Core Installer` from the [.NET Core downloads page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download).

Since then my build tasks are running and successfully building my website, but not actually running any web deploy publishing. It is not failing - it is just not being run.

I want to stress I am talking about a 'legacy' .NET application - not a .NET Core application. I just installed .NET Core for somebody else.

I can verify this with the following observations:

- There are no errors in any event viewers (except ones that are months old)
- There is no message in the msbuild logfile that says `Start Web Deploy Publish`, however log files from just a couple days ago do have this message.
- I can connect to the local server at port 8172 and it makes a connection.
- It is happening with multiple projects that nobody else has access to.
- `_PublishedWebsites` *does* get created with the latest files - it just never gets deployed anywhere.

What could possibly have broken this? Did the `Windows Server Hosting` package break it - or was it just some other update that came in? I've run out of ideas how to fix it and don't want to revert to xcopy!

Comment: I'm using the `XAML builds`

Comment: A blind guess: Have a look at the path environment variables if something fishy after the installation (i.e. if the path variable became to long and cut after .NET Core SDK/runtime got installed)

Comment: @Tseng will check it out. Also installed visual studio 2015 and TFS express update 3 hoping that may reset something.

Comment: @Tseng phew - installing VS2015 and TFS express fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it :-) Not sure exactly which of these steps did it, but I suspect it was Visual studio.

I was using `TFS Express 2015` and upgraded to Update 3.

I also installed `Visual Studio 2015` on the server itself.

I had previously had `.NET Core RC2` (or whatever they called it at the time) installed and I uninstalled that before installing `.NET Core RTM`. Wondering if that removed some component that was required.

Like I said everything was working fine before I installed the .NET Core RTM - but fortunately installing VS and TFS brought everything back to normal.